# Button text not vertically aligning in IE 10

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button with text, the text doesn't seem to align align vertically within the button. This only happens on IE 10. Chrome is perfect.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="postcode" name="Postcode" class="input" placeholder="enter your postcode..." maxlength="8" size="10"><button class="button" type="submit" id="postcode">FIND DEALS</button>
```

CSS

```
.banner-input button{
    background: #0072bc;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 108px;
    height: 54px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #00548a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 1px 0px,#2888c7 0px 1px 0px inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 1px 0px,#2888c7 0px 1px 0px inset;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 1px 0px,#2888c7 0px 1px 0px inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #005f9c;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FF0072BC', endColorstr='#FF005F9C');
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #f7b814), color-stop(100%, #ff9100));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0072bc 0%, #005f9c 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0072bc 0%, #005f9c 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0072bc 0%, #005f9c 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0072bc 0%, #005f9c 100%);
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have tried various line-height's and paddings. Nothing seems to work. :(

Comment: Vertical-align is only for cells... And for me is aligned... Only It have to have 3px of left padding more on the button....

Comment: Check it out here: http://swiftping.co/development/msb/page.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it. It was the font I was using.

Myriad Pro appears quite a bit different on IE compared too Chrome and Firefox. I changed it to Open Sans and now the text is aligned correctly on all three.

Comment: This is a wise decision!)

Answer (score 2):

Try to set line-height = height --> `line-height: 54px;`

Comment: When I do that it seems to be lower down on Chrome. I think that's due to the font however as the font's height is slightly less on Chrome than IE. Thanks though.

Comment: I agree with, maybe there is because of font. I don't work with Myriad Pro and I can't say if it cross-browser. I think in this way be better starting from searching cross-browser line-height. At first try to set line-heiht: 1.2em; text don't be align vertically, but if text will be in the same level in different browsers - this is what you need. If this don't help you try to set line-height = font-size*1.2 (18 px) and check the level again. Repeat this, each time increasing the line-height by 1 (19, 20 ...) until you find the cross-browser if it exists at all. Then set the padding align text.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting the padding for your button? I don't see that in your css.

Your line-height seems too high. If your height is 50px and your padding is 10px (top and bottom) then yor line-height should be 30 and so on

Comment: I have no padding set on the button, I have currently set the line-height = height. At the moment the text is slightly higher than the center on IE and slightly lower on Chrome. http://www.swiftping.co.uk/development/msb/page.html

Answer (score 0):

In case where you can't change the font (specific to the client's design) you can put a **detectizr** to detect the version of the Browser, the operation system and even the kind of device. After that, you can target directly that element. Here is an example in Sass for your button.

```
.ie { .btn-something { padding-top: 15px; } }
```